# Showing a homotopy function is a proper map

Tags: real-analysis, homotopy-theory

I got stuck with the following question. Can you provide me any hint to proceed? Thanks in advance.

From continuity, i know that inverse of any compact set will be closed. However, how am i supposed to show that that set is bounded?

Let $f$, $g$ be non constant monic polynomials with complex coefficients. Then consider the homotopy function,
$$
F: [ 0,1 ] \times \mathbb { C } \rightarrow \mathbb { C } , ( t , z ) \mapsto ( 1 - t ) f ( z ) + t g ( z )
$$
Show that $F$ is proper if and only if $\operatorname { deg } ( f ) = \operatorname { deg } ( g )$.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: At the beginning, I got stuck. Although I know the definitions I couldn't come up with a proper start. I have to show that for any compact set in C, inverse image of that set has to be compact. So, I need to show that inverse image of the set is bounded and closed.

Comment: Well, clearly since this function is continuous inverse of any compact set will be closed as well. I'm having trouble in showing boundedness.